# Azure VM Security Center scans seem to be innacurate; how to force a re-scan?

Tags: azure, azure-security

I'm having an issue with Azure Security Center that I'm hoping someone could help me out with.

I have multiple Red Hat Linux VMs in several resource groups under one subscription. When I initially ran through the capabilities of Azure Security Center, there were multiple recommendations for system updates, firewall settings, etc. that I was told to apply on my systems, which I went ahead and did. My scans on the VMs themselves come up clean, with everything installed and up to date.

Unfortunately, Security Center thinks that they are still out of date, and if I check the last scan time, some are over 2 weeks old; is there any way to force a re-scan of the system? Or am I just supposed to wait until Azure feels like re-scanning?

Example: [some VMs that aren't re-scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lKGq.png)

Also, a related question: Security Center has re-scanned systems that I know are up to date, but still recommends system updates. How is Azure scanning these systems? Is there somewhere that I can specify the versions for the updates that it is suggesting I update?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever able to figure this out? Last time I spoke with Azure Support they told me it takes 24-48 hours, and no manual option to rescan.